# How to send a JSON payload with REST API in Grails?

Tags: json, rest, grails

I am trying to call a `REST API` with `JSON` payload using `Grails` and getting error below.

I have already converted the object to `JSON` earlier here and passing it in.  Not sure what am I missing.

**SpotifyService.groovy**

```
@Transactional
class SpotifyService implements EventPublisher {

    String spotifyServiceBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:9999'
    String username = "abcd"
    String password = "defg"

    void createSoldOrder(ItemDetails itemDetails) {
        println("into the createSoldOrder method......")
        String orderId = "100-200-ABC"
        String soldDate = itemDetails.order.orderDate
        String partnerUniqueId = itemDetails.customer.billingAddress.email
        def monthEndDate = new Date() + 30
        String commitEndDate = monthEndDate.toString()
        String product = "premium-month"
        String soldMetadata = "Partner's metadata connected to the sold order"
        String partnerDeals = "hardbundle*3,standalone"
        NewOrder newOrder = new NewOrder(orderId: orderId, soldDate: soldDate, partnerUniqueId: partnerUniqueId,
                commitEndDate: commitEndDate, product: product, soldMetadata: soldMetadata,
                partnerDeals: partnerDeals)
        println("newOrder: " + newOrder)
        String newOrderJsonPayload = new JsonBuilder(newOrder).toPrettyString()
        println("newOrderJsonPayload: " + newOrderJsonPayload)
        placeSpotifyOrder(newOrderJsonPayload)
    }

    void placeSpotifyOrder(String newOrderJsonPayload) {
        println("into the placeSpotifyOrder method........")
        String restUrl = spotifyServiceBaseUrl + "/order-sold"
        println restUrl
        RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
        RestResponse restResponse = rest.post(restUrl) {
            auth username, password
            json {
                newOrderJsonPayload
            }
        }
        if (restResponse.statusCode.value()) {
            println(restResponse.text)
        }
        null
    }

}
```

**Error:**

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '{
    "product": "premium-month",
    "orderId": "100-200-ABC",
    "soldMetadata": "Partner's metadata connected to the sold order",
    "partnerUniqueId": "success@simulator.amazonses.com",
    "commitEndDate": "Sat Mar 24 16:51:37 EDT 2018",
    "soldDate": "2017-08-03T20:07:27+0000",
    "partnerDeals": "hardbundle*3,standalone"
}' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'grails.converters.JSON'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:405)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:319)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:232)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:15669)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods.asType(StringGroovyMethods.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$1048.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:913)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:904)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:591)
    at grails.web.JSONBuilder.build(JSONBuilder.groovy:42)
    at grails.plugins.rest.client.RequestCustomizer.json(RequestCustomizer.groovy:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1433)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at com.synapsegroupinc.spotifyintegrator.SpotifyService$__tt__placeSpotifyOrder_closure4.doCall(SpotifyService.groovy:50)
```

Comment: Leave out the `newOrderJsonPayload` step

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class with all the properties you need in the json object. Create an instance of the class and populate its properties. Then use `objInstance as JSON` to covert it to json.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem connected with Method `json{}`. The method is overloaded. If you want to send payload as `json string` you should change your code in `placeSpotifyOrder` as following:

```
RestResponse restResponse = rest.post(restUrl) {
      auth (username, password)
      json (newOrderJsonPayload)            
}
```

Comment: @user2325154, My answer is showed reason why the exception was thrown and if in case when the request body can be only string.